# Soundex in MySQL Query not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database, soundex

I have the task of making a query that finds content through a database even if it is mispelled when searched so I'm using strcmp to compare the soundex in my queries. Problem with my current code. If I search AZUS and I mean ASUS and there's a title with ASUS it doesn't show up. That's because in the `post_entry` ASUS is `<a href="">ASUS </a>` so I would have to do `soundex("%'.$arraytagsd.'")` in my code below taking out a `%` to do this however for every option %s% or %s  or s% or s would make my script slow.

Is there anyway of doing this faster still using soundex?

I created this function to take each word of the search input and compare it to the database

```
$colname_getPosts = $_GET['post_title'];
mysql_select_db($database_Main);
function test($string) {
    $output = '';
    $arrays = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach ($arrays as $arraytagsd) {
        $output .= ' OR strcmp(soundex(post_title), soundex("%'.$arraytagsd.'%")) = 0';
        $output .= ' OR strcmp(soundex(post_entry), soundex("%'.$arraytagsd.'%")) = 0';
        $output .= ' OR strcmp(soundex(tags), soundex("%'.$arraytagsd.'%")) = 0';
        $output .= ' OR strcmp(soundex(post_author), soundex("%'.$arraytagsd.'%")) = 0';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I use it in my query which sorts by relevance

```
$query_getPosts = "
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, sum(relevance)
FROM (
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 10 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(post_title) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 2 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(post_author) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)".test($colname_getPosts)." 
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 5 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(post_entry) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
UNION
SELECT post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags, 7 AS relevance FROM blog_posts WHERE MATCH(tags) AGAINST('%$colname_getPosts%' IN BOOLEAN MODE))results
GROUP BY post_id, post_date, post_title, post_author, post_entry, tags ORDER BY relevance DESC";
$getPosts = mysql_query($query_getPosts) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getPosts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPosts);
$totalRows_getPosts = mysql_num_rows($getPosts);
?>
```

Comment: for clarification: I would have to do "%'.$arraytagsd.'%"; then "'.$arraytagsd.'%" then "%'.$arraytagsd.'" then "'.$arraytagsd.'" which slows the script down

Comment: `"%'.$arraytagsd.'%"` would match all 4 of the suggested expressions, since `%` matches 0 or more characters (like `*` in regex), **not** 1 or more characters (like `+` in regex)

Comment: ...although having said that, does `%` make any sense in the context of soundex anyway? I can't see it mentioned anywhere in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)...

Comment: soundex wont result in very good search results...

Comment: idk but when I was using my code above it wasnt working. I also decided to go with the answer you had before because it looked neater. you should post an answer

Comment: Randy what would be a good alternative though. definitely not metaphone

Comment: @kdogisthebest could you please update your uestion with your soundex implementation has answer am also stuck with it :) please help its urgent thanks :)

Comment: I actualy got rid of it and I use sphinx now on a vps

Comment: does sphinx provide the same functionalty you asked for in php /mysql

Comment: Yes. This integrates right into mysql to with the Sphinx Engine. But you must learn how to correctly use it though. They create restrictions on your table format.

Comment: If your using sphinx now you should edit the question to include that because the way to approach this with sphinx is much different then with straight mysql

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using solr for this, but if you want to do it in mysql, here is what I'd do.

1. For columns where you are doing this search, make separate soundex columns.  Like:  product_name, product_name_soundex.
2. To populate product_name_soundex, you are going to have to do a bunch of stuff in code:  a) retrieve a product name, b) tokenize the name, c) calculate the soundex (but consider using double metaphone) for each token, d) store the resulting string in product_name_soundex.  This might look like product_name: Tonka Toy Truck product_name_soundex: T2242 T592 T2321.
3. Create a fulltext index on product_name, and one on product_name_soundex.
4. Write your such that you use the same tokenization and soundex algothrithms as you did to build the _soundex columns.